# OGRE linking to boost fails, OSX 10.7

Tags: macos, boost, ogre, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to install groovy on my mac running lion.  After appropriate tapping and following the instructions, brew install ogre (or brew install ros/groovy/ogre) gets me the following.  I noticed in one of the patches that boost versions are only listed for up to 1.46.1, so I also tried reverting back to that version of boost via homebrew.  I was using the newest in the homebrew repo, 1.53.0.  It seems as though its just not getting the right flags, but I was concerned at it seems no one else has had this problem.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

```
Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libOgreMain.dylib
brew: superenv removed: -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "boost::this_thread::interruption_point()", referenced from:
 boost::condition_variable::wait(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&) in OgreWorkQueue.cpp.o
  
...

boost::detail::thread_data_base::thread_data_base() in OgreDefaultWorkQueueStandard.cpp.o
NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [lib/libOgreMain.1.7.4.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [OgreMain/CMakeFiles/OgreMain.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
==> Configuration
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.4
HEAD: 3e262a61605d8a635b67e29023de2134a2a8ea9d
CPU: quad-core 64-bit sandybridge
OS X: 10.7.5-x86_64
Xcode: 4.6.2
CLT: 1.0.0.9000000000.1.1249367152
LLVM-GCC: build 2336
Clang: 4.0 build 421
X11: 2.6.5 => /usr/X11
==> ENV
HOMEBREW_CC: clang
MAKEFLAGS: -j4
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /usr/local/opt/freetype:/usr/local
CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH: /usr/X11/include/freetype2:/usr/include/libxml2:/usr/X11/include
CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/X11/lib
PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/freetype/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/libzzip/lib/pkgconfig
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR: /usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/X11/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/X11/share/pkgconfig
ACLOCAL_PATH: /usr/local/opt/freetype/share/aclocal:/usr/local/share/aclocal
OBJC: cc
PATH: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3:/usr/local/opt/cmake/bin:/usr/local/opt/doxygen/bin:/usr/local/opt/freetype/bin:/usr/local/opt/libzzip/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63503/ogre-linking-to-boost-fails,-osx-10.7/) by [Mike Shomin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1719/mike-shomin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-05-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-05-26**:
I am not sure what the problem is, but all I can tell you is that I use boost 1.53 and it works fine for me.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-05-29**:
I can reproduce this problem now, looks like Ogre is going to need a patch of some sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just posted a fix to the ogre formulae on the ros-groovy tap:

https://github.com/ros/homebrew-groovy/commit/12e84193bb59f7230d8523b3e44726906fd66aac

Try doing:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install ogre
```

Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Shomin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1719/mike-shomin/) on 2013-05-30**:
As always William, you have the answers/solutions.  Thanks again for all your OSX/Homebrew/Github work.  Much appreciated.